# Calling Functions of a child contract using an owner contract

Tags: contract-development, remix, tokens, contract-invocation

I had deployed a smart contract (contract #1) that uses another smart contract (#2) for some transaction logic. Contract #2 was imported in the first contract itself and deployed with the help of Remix IDE.

Now, I have some setter functions that the owner can only run on these contracts.
What I didn't realize what that when contract #2 gets deployed, its owner is contract #1. So I can't access the setter function of #2 using metamask as its owner is contract #1.

Is there any way I can access those setter functions of contract #2? Can anyone help with this, otherwise I'll be in huge trouble.

Comment: Some code snippets related to owner-related places in your contract would be highly appreciated

Comment: You should add unit test for the functionality you want to use.